# Measuring frequency and amplitude of analog signal with Labview

Tags: labview

I'm preparing for a lab where I will measure the frequency and amplitude of a tuning fork optically. From my setup, I will get a signal corresponding to the number of millimeters of displacement the tuning fork currently has. I expect this signal will look like a sine wave and that the amplitude will decrease over time.

This is the signal I will send to LabView via GPIB. It will probably have some noise. What is the best approach to find the frequency and amplitude of the signal?

How do I implement this in LabView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some inbuilt examples in LabView, Please check **"Find Examples"**

Help-->Find Examples-->Select Search Tab -->Type in "**Tone**" within the Enter Keywords Text Box.

**Basic Single Tone Measurement.vi**

Hope that helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a reasonably clean signal then just count the number of zero crossings in a given period of time and calculate the frequency from that. Use hysteresis to eliminate the effect of noise. For the amplitude just measure the size of the first few peaks.

If it's a noisy signal then you probably want to use an FFT to generate a power spectrum and get the amplitude and frequency from the largest peak in the spectrum.

Comment: Let's assume that the signal is reasonably clean. What group of functions should I use to implement this? There seem to be a lot of functions relating specifically to analog waveforms, would any of those be helpful? "Build wave", "max min" and so on...

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't talk at all about how to implement those strategies in LabView. I know the definition of frequency, I know Fourier Analysis, etc. but in LabView, what is the best way of measuring the signal period, continuously? This is what I need to know to find the frequency without FFT. It's purely a problem about programming with LabView, and I can't find anything about that.

Comment: Well there's an FFT Power Spectrum VI - perhaps that would be easier ? You could also try asking on the NI LabView Forum.